# I want to use PhantomJS to parse a dynamic website

Tags: python, path

I run the following code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\Users\a1nag\OneDrive\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip\phantomjs- 
2.1.1-windows\bin")
driver.get("https://www.paddypower.com/mixed-martial-arts")

# waiting for the page to load - TODO: change
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content")))

data = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

I get the following error:

```
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
WebDriverException: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have used python before, but only for data analysis and visualisation, so terminology regarding path goes over my head. I thought I included path where phantomjs is in the correct place. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\Users\a1nag\OneDrive\Desktop\phantomjs- 
2.1.1-windows.zip\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe")
driver.get("https://www.paddypower.com/mixed-martial-arts")

# waiting for the page to load - TODO: change
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "content")))

data = driver.page_source
driver.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
```

Get exactly the same error message: "os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)

WebDriverException: 'phantomjs.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. "

And, thank you for the help!

Edit: I put the .exe file in a folder that is in the path. I get a different error, so I assumed it has worked. Thanks again

Comment: did you check what parameters use `PhantomJS()` ? In `Firefox()` first parameter is assigned to `firefox_profile=` and you have to assign `.exe` to `executable_path=` or something similar.

Comment: you have to put `phantomjs.exe` in folder which you have in system variable `PATH`. OR folder in which you have `phantomjs.exe` you have to add to system variable `PATH`.

Comment: you have to use full path with `phantomjs.exe` - `PhantomJS("C:\...\phantomjs.exe")`

Comment: I originally included phantomjs.exe and that didnt work, so I copied the path address from the file explorer directly.

Comment: I wonder why you have folder with `.zip` and maybe it is compressed ZIP file and file manager shows you what you have inside this ZIP file - but you have to uncompress it and use full path to `phantomjs.exe` after uncompressing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use full path with `phantomjs.exe` at the end

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(r"C:\Users\a1nag\OneDrive\Desktop\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe")
```

---

Eventually you have to put `phantomjs.exe` in folder which you can find on system variable `PATH` and then you can run without argument.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

Or you have to add full path (without `phantomjs.exe`)  to system variable `PATH` and then you can also run it without argument.

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```